# Pass mapper as type and use methods on generic type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping

So I've created a base repository class which returns domain models and uses entity objects to manipulate data in the database. Here is the repository class:

```
public abstract class Repository<TDomain, TEntity, TMapper> : IReadWriteRepository<TDomain>
    where TDomain : Model
    where TEntity : Entity
    where TMapper : IMapper<TDomain, TEntity>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<TDomain> Get()
    {
        var entities = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        // Return domain models
    }

    public void Add(TDomain item)
    {
        // Convert to entity model
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);
    }

    public void Update(TDomain item)
    {
        // Convert domain to entity model
        var entry = _context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

As you can see at this point I'm struggling to convert the entity objects to domain and vice versa.

I have defined an `IMapper` interface which when implemented will convert entity into domain and vice versa.

```
public interface IMapper<TDomain, TEntity> where TDomain : Model where TEntity : Entity
{
    public TDomain ToDomain(TEntity entity);
    public TEntity ToEntity(TDomain domain);
}
```

**Problem:**

I can't seem to use any of these methods in the `Repository` base class through `TMapper`, I basically want to be able to just have 1 simple Repository implementation which performs all CRUD operations but using multiple `Mappers` to assist with mapping objects.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need `TMapper`. Why not inject an `IMapper<TDomain, TEntity>` via the constructor?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I was thinking to inject `IMapper<TDomain, TEntity>`. The issue is, how would I DI a particular instance of `IMapper` when I can have multiple repositories with different mapper implementations?

Comment: So you have multiple mappers for the same `TDomain` & `TEntity`? If so, then you could retain `TMapper` and inject one of those instead.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I have multiple mappers for different domain models and entities. I need to be able to inject different mappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call methods just using a generic type, you need an actual object, and such an object would typically be injected in the constructor:

```
public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context, TMapper mapper)
{
    _context = context;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

Note that there is no real advantage making the mapper generic, you could just inject a `IMapper<TDomain, TEntity>` instead. If you are using a DI container you would need to register a mapper for each `TDomain`/`TEntity`-pair. Different DI containers might work differently, but I would expect that if you resolve `Repository<MyDomain, MyEntity>` the container should look for `IMapper<MyDomain, MyEntity>`, and if you registered an implementation for that interface it should all work out.

You might however consider using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead. This would allow you to create a single class that take care of converting all entities to domain objects, or vice versa. I tend to like this method since the compiler can force you to add any missing mappings when you add new types.